# An exposition on crystallographic point groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am a maths undergraduate student, and have done introductory course on finite groups (following "Topics in Algebra" by I. N. Herstein). This semester I am taking a course on crystallography (a compulsory inter-disciplinary course) and have failed to follow the concept of "point groups" (which other chemistry and biology major people are finding easy to follow). I am feeling very uncomfortable while trying to relate the purely abstract treatment of finite groups with the physical treatment of symmetry elements.

I will be grateful if someone could point to articles discussing the concept of point groups from a mathematician's point of view and then discussing its relation with crystallography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group) about point groups gives a first survey. For more details, and a mathematical treatment see for example the book [Geometry of Crystallographic Groups](https://books.google.at/books?id=wX26CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=crystallographic+groups+szepanski&source=bl&ots=r823kSSE-j&sig=1GdQVJ-4rTGL0jiB6yesuDeyyqA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE_7bW6O7SAhViLcAKHXDfCgMQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=crystallographic%20groups%20szepanski&f=false) by Andrzej Szczepanski. For a nice online slide talk about is see for example [here](http://www.irb.hr/users/mdsikir/Presentations/CrystGroup.pdf). If $G$ is a crystallographic group, then $G/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is its point group.